# Strncat causes exception

Tags: c

I am making a program in c to read a file and execute different pieces of code depending on what is in the file. However, when I try to read the file I get an exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x7C3306DD (ucrtbased.dll) in MacroTool.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000068.
```

Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("ERR: too few arguments.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        printf("ERR: too many arguments.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("ERR: cannot read file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char buf[100];

    char c;

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        strncat(buf, c, 1);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Using multiple search engines to find an answer that is related to this issue led to nothing.

I am using windows 10 and visual studio 2019

Comment: You've probably reached the 99th character in `buf` (100th is `\0`), and attempted to add one more character. You could print `buf` inside the while loop.

Comment: Enable all warnings to save time.  `strncat(buf, c, 1);` --> 2nd parameter is wrong type.

Comment: Ooof! Trying to access memory in the System Reserved memory region is guaranteed to do bad things... `Access violation reading location 0x00000068` Points clearly to a pointer being abused...

Comment: `size_t n = 0; while (n + 1 < 100 && (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { buf[n++] = c; } buf[n] = 0;`

Comment: You should get an error message for `strncat(buf, c, 1);` . If you don't, then immediately stop what you're doing and fix your compiler settings  , it just causes you to waste time trying to run incorrect code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to use a string-funciton on a buffer that is not *nul-terminated* resulting in *Undefined Behavior*. Specifically:

```
    char buf[100];

    char c;

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        strncat(buf, c, 1);
```

On your first call to `strncat`, `buf` in uninitialized resulting in *Undefined Behavior* due to `strncat()` replacing the existing *nul-terminating* character (which doesn't exist) with the new text to be appended. You can initialize `buf` all zero with:

```
    char buf[100] = "";
```

That will fix the immediate *Undefined Behavior* but will not prevent you later reading beyond the bounds of `buf` when you read past the 99th character.

Instead, declare a counter and initialize the counter zero, and use that to limit the number of characters read into your `buf`, as in the comment:

```
    size_t n = 0;
    
    while (n + 1 < 100 && (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { 
        buf[n++] = c;
    }
    buf[n] = 0;      /* don't forget to nul-terminate buf */
```

You can put it altogether and avoid using *Magic-Numbers* (`100`) as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 100        /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    
    if (argc < 2) { /* validate one argument given for filename */
        fputs ("error: too few arguments.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    char buf[MAXC] = "", c;
    size_t n = 0;
    FILE* fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {                   /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("fopen-argv[1]");       /* on failure, perror() tells why */
        return 1;
    }

    /* while buf not full (saving 1-char for \0), read char */
    while (n + 1 < MAXC && (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        buf[n++] = c;                   /* assign char to next element in buf */

    buf[n] = 0;                         /* nul-terminate buf */
    
    puts (buf);                         /* output result */
    
    fclose(fp);
}
```

(**note:** the comparison with `n + 1` ensures one-element in `buf` remains for the *nul-terminating* character)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/read100chars read100chars.c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 100        /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

in
```

(**note:** the first `'n'` in `int main (...` is the 99th character in the file)

Look thing over and let me know if you need further help. (note with VS you will likely need to pass `/w4996` to disable the `"CRT Secure...."` warning.)

Answer (score 2):

```
char *strncat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);
```

https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat

> The strcat() function appends the src string to the dest string, overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of dest, and then adds a terminating null byte. The strings may not overlap, and the dest string must have enough space for the result. If dest is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable; buffer overruns are a favorite avenue for attacking secure programs.

Note that strncat will take 2 pointers, first the destination and the second is the source, you're providing a character so it should be `strncat(buf, &c, 1);`

the strncat will start appending characters at the end of the destination, ie. at the null byte, and since your buffer isn't initialized, it contains noise and may not contain nullbyte '\0' inside. The `strncat` try searching the `\0` starting from `buff` and it may find somewhere after the array ends and start to append characters there. and that's why you get error `Access violation writing location 0x68FB49FC` to fix this set the first byte of your buffer to `\0`

```c
char buf[100];
buf[0] = '\0';
```

Also you don't check if your buffer has space for the new character, which also leads to access violation that if your source file contains more than 99 characters. you also have to handle that as well

1. limit your loop by 99 characters (and print an error if it's exceeded)
2. make your buffer enough like `char buf[2048];` or something but still, it'll crash if it's not enough
3. create a buffer with the size of your source

```c
size_t getFileSize(FILE* _file) {
    fseek(_file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t _size = ftell(_file);
    fseek(_file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    return _size;
}
```

```
char* buf = malloc(getFileSize(fp)); //< you have to manage the allocated memory
```

**And one more thing**

you're trying to read a file into a buffer by `strncat` this might be in efficient since every time it needs to get the `strlen`, check the size `n` and add both character and `\0`. Instead, I recommend

```c
char* readFile(FILE* _file) {
    size_t file_size = getFileSize(_file);

    char* buf = malloc(file_size + 1);
    size_t read = fread(buf, sizeof(char), file_size, _file);
    buf[read] = '\0';

    return buf;
}
```

Comment: The fseek/ftell method is only reliable for files opened in binary mode (OP is opening in text mode)